# What is the value of encoders with decoders currently present

Tags: php, security

Can you tell me the value of using PHP encoder (ioncube, phpshield) with currently present service like decry.pt (http://www.decry.pt/) that can easily decode source codes.

I have tried decry.pt's free demo. Just drag & drop an encoded source and it will return the decoded one. It is so easy.

It seems the value of encoder can be easily be canceled.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me the value of using PHP encoder (ioncube, phpshield) with currently present service like decry.pt (http://www.decry.pt/) that can easily decode source codes.

The value is that the source code is no longer readable by humans.

> I have tried decry.pt's free demo. Just drag & drop an encoded source and it will return the decoded one. It is so easy.

Yes, that is correct. The source code is only obfuscated.

> It seems the value of encoder can be easily be canceled.

There is no security or copy-protection provided by obfuscation.

What you are looking for is **encryption** and not obfuscation. There are a few encryption engines out there, but they all require the following to work.

- a license for the end-user to decrypt the source code.
- encryption algorithm that uses a public/private key pair
- software installed on the web server to decrypt the source code.

There is no way for anyone to decrypt the source code unless they have the private key. [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard) uses a licensing engine, source code encryption and an internal memory cache.

Comment: Do you know a good PHP encryptor?

Comment: Your reply is mostly incorrect Mathew. While there's value in protecting source from dishonest people, more value is often found in licensing code to honest (and paying!) people. With ionCube and a few others source code is compiled & gone, not hidden and obfuscated; very different! The biggest issue with tools is that decoding keys are embedded in or provided with encoded files. ionCube 9 addresses this & can decrypt compiled bytecode using algorithmic keys that don't exist statically anywhere, being only computed at runtime, which is a game changer. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Comment: @Nick Sorry, didn't mean to imply that I knew how ioncube worked. Haven't used it before. I was referring to the tools that read a PHP file and write out an obfuscated PHP file. Often placing the source code in a scrambled string that is decoded on the fly. Like many of the JavaScript obfuscators.

Comment: No problem :) Actually we have such an obfuscator for Javascript that a customer donated to us years back, and the reason we never charged for it is because we felt it would be almost dishonest to do so, even though people would have paid us for it. There are obfuscators for PHP too, and they can successfully hamper understanding of code, but obviously don't protect code. In our experience, while it's not nice if people use code without paying, you really need to enforce licensing and not have unsustainable upgrade policies such as free upgrades for life.

Answer (score 1):

First, be aware that no software can ever be 100% protected from reverse engineering and decompilation, and sites such as the one you mention just illustrate this. They also illustrate that recreating code is hard to do because they tend not to work that well on applications as a whole if using all protection options that systems tend to provide, but regardless, providers of encoding systems should be evolving their technologies over time to move ahead of any progress that hackers have made. It's good practice to ensure that you're using the latest version of any protection tool when making a new major release.

You mentioned value, and in determining potential value of any DRM system, you need first to understand where your risks to revenue lie.  For example, are you seeking and likely to get most value by preventing someone who has no intention of purchasing getting a stolen copy of your application (or might doing so actually hurt revenue long term?), or is there more value from preventing the scenario of someone who is basically honest and happy to have paid to use code on one server, but who is now using it on several more without paying any extra when they tried it and found that it works because you did nothing to enforce a licensing policy? If we go for the latter and let's say your paying customer is a company, is that company paying hackers to try and break an application in order to work around a license going to make sense and be a smart business decision for them, or is it a business risk? Given that the results of breaking code are likely to be buggy, there will be no updates available and original bug fixes from the application providers, and there's a risk of legal action and loss of trust and therefore sales when publically exposed as crooks by the application provider or a bitter ex-employee, the smart choice is to be honest and lock in the benefits that doing so gives. Whilst there will be some exceptions to this, provided that an application is sensibly priced and is provided by a responsible company, in general end users shouldn't be *interested* in trying to "break" it even if they could.

So for many, that's essentially the answer here, with the biggest risk realistically not from hacker sites but in poor revenue protection from lack of licensing. What you must do as the application provider is ensure that you have a license policy that makes sound business sense and that you do something to enforce it, be it DRM or something else, otherwise you cannot complain when you lose revenue as a result.

Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube and ionCube 24.